# Rerender view after change route's dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have a Route with dynamic segment :id. When I change only the dynamic segement part manually in browser url input field, then goes a transition, and all model hooks are called as expected.

The problem is: none of the views are rerendered. I guess it is because only model changed - not the UI. But I have some UI logic in views' didInsertElement handler - reinitialize UI plugins and so on.

How to force ember to rerender view after dynamic segment change?

Comment: My first thought is: do you really want your entire view to re-render, or do you just want the view to reflect an update in your model?

Ember is setup to have two-way binding by default, but sometimes it's possible to write code that removes the two-way binding.  Without seeing your code or a JSBin, it's hard to know what your issue is, but, in general, you would want to make sure two-way bindings are intact between your view and subview.  One way to test this is to add in an `{{input}}` helper that access the same model property, type in it directly, and see if your parent view updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the josh's comment. if you are rerendering views with the change of dynamic segment means your code is not written properly. But still if you want to go like that i am gonna give is a part of code.

In your route:

```
model: function(params){
   model.set('id', params.id);
}
```

In your view which needs to be rerendered:

```
_modelIdChange: function(){
  this.rerender();
}.observes('controller.model.id')
```

But i don't suggest this. I would rather prefer proper bindings. But i did use rerendering in some cases which mostly when you end up using jquery plugins.

Comment: Using jQuery plugins is exactly the case here. I have a editing form with a lot of different inputs - datepickers, select views and so on, for which I use jquery plugins. The problem is - when I change the id of model - new model is loaded, and input's values are updated, but if for example I opened a datepicker before - it is still opened after model change, and preserves user's input - which is wrong, I expect it refreshed. And also copy-pasting modelIdChange handlers for all the nested views doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: Actually your advice worked for me. I created a view backing my route and added modelIdChanged handler. So when model id changes, the whole view with all nested component views is rerendered. Thanks!