# How to rerender a routes template when only a dynamic part of the url changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

First off: I know about this answer: [Rerender view after change route's dynamic segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065754/rerender-view-after-change-routes-dynamic-segment)

Problem is: views are deprecated in ember-1.13 and we should not use them.

My use case is: I have an instance of ckEditor running on the page and it does not update the value that is inside the `<textarea>` its been attached to properly (the value in the `<textarea>` is in fact updated due to embers binding). I tried to put an observer on the models id like in the answer above suggested, and then destroy and recreate the editor. But heres the next problem: the dom is not updated yet when the observer fires, so the ckEditor gets recreated with the same content as before. So I actually DO need to rerender the whole template. How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `this.refresh()` in an action of the route?

Comment: I did that in `didTransition` but that has lead to an endless loop. I don't like to call an action AND a link-to but I definitely want to use `link-to`. I did solved the ckeditor problem by setting the new data explicitly when the model changes.